# Apache server freezes until it gets restarted

Tags: apache-2.2

I have a Dedicated server from Hetzner Datacenter which i use it as Download server(file host) :

- Intel® Core™ i7-2600 Quadcore incl. Hyper-Threading Technology
- 32 GB DDR3 RAM
- 100mb/s bandwidth
- Centos 6.3
- Apache/2.2.24 (Unix)

I am using prefork.c and i set that like this :

```
<IfModule prefork.c>
StartServers 5
MinSpareServers 10
MaxSpareServers 15
ServerLimit 4000
MaxClients 4000
MaxRequestsPerChild 0
</IfModule>
```

but when the traffic goes up, Apache server freezes until it gets restarted. where the problem is?

output of  : sysctl -a

kernel.sched_child_runs_first = 0
    kernel.sched_min_granularity_ns = 4000000
    kernel.sched_latency_ns = 20000000
    kernel.sched_wakeup_granularity_ns = 4000000
    kernel.sched_tunable_scaling = 1
    kernel.sched_features = 3183
    kernel.sched_migration_cost = 500000
    kernel.sched_nr_migrate = 32
    kernel.sched_time_avg = 1000
    kernel.sched_shares_window = 10000000
    kernel.timer_migration = 1
    kernel.sched_rt_period_us = 1000000
    kernel.sched_rt_runtime_us = 950000
    kernel.sched_compat_yield = 0
    kernel.sched_autogroup_enabled = 0
    kernel.sched_cfs_bandwidth_slice_us = 5000
    kernel.panic = 0
    kernel.exec-shield = 1
    kernel.core_uses_pid = 1
    kernel.core_pattern = |/usr/libexec/abrt-hook-ccpp %s %c %p %u %g %t e
    kernel.core_pipe_limit = 4
    kernel.tainted = 0
    kernel.real-root-dev = 0
    kernel.print-fatal-signals = 0
    kernel.ctrl-alt-del = 0
    kernel.ftrace_enabled = 1
    kernel.stack_tracer_enabled = 0
    kernel.ftrace_dump_on_oops = 0
    kernel.modprobe = /sbin/modprobe
    kernel.modules_disabled = 0
    kernel.kexec_load_disabled = 0
    kernel.hotplug =
    kernel.acct = 4    2    30
    kernel.sysrq = 0
    kernel.cad_pid = 1
    kernel.threads-max = 508572
    kernel.random.poolsize = 4096
    kernel.random.entropy_avail = 305
    kernel.random.read_wakeup_threshold = 64
    kernel.random.write_wakeup_threshold = 128
    kernel.random.boot_id = de5e6691-98e5-4dca-990d-310b2a0710d7
    kernel.random.uuid = 83eb9637-d234-4150-b088-5092f2f41b7e
    kernel.usermodehelper.bset = 4294967295    4294967295
    kernel.usermodehelper.inheritable = 4294967295    4294967295
    kernel.overflowuid = 65534
    kernel.overflowgid = 65534
    kernel.pid_max = 32768
    kernel.panic_on_oops = 1
    kernel.printk = 4    4    1    7
    kernel.printk_ratelimit = 5
    kernel.printk_ratelimit_burst = 10
    kernel.printk_delay = 0
    kernel.dmesg_restrict = 0
    kernel.kptr_restrict = 1
    kernel.ngroups_max = 65536
    kernel.watchdog = 1
    kernel.watchdog_thresh = 60
    kernel.softlockup_panic = 0
    kernel.nmi_watchdog = 1
    kernel.unknown_nmi_panic = 0
    kernel.panic_on_unrecovered_nmi = 0
    kernel.panic_on_io_nmi = 0
    kernel.bootloader_type = 113
    kernel.bootloader_version = 1
    kernel.kstack_depth_to_print = 12
    kernel.io_delay_type = 0
    kernel.randomize_va_space = 2
    kernel.acpi_video_flags = 0
    kernel.hung_task_panic = 0
    kernel.hung_task_check_count = 4194304
    kernel.hung_task_timeout_secs = 120
    kernel.hung_task_warnings = 10
    kernel.compat-log = 1
    kernel.max_lock_depth = 1024
    kernel.poweroff_cmd = /sbin/poweroff
    kernel.keys.maxkeys = 200
    kernel.keys.maxbytes = 20000
    kernel.keys.root_maxkeys = 200
    kernel.keys.root_maxbytes = 20000
    kernel.keys.gc_delay = 300
    kernel.slow-work.min-threads = 2
    kernel.slow-work.max-threads = 8
    kernel.slow-work.vslow-percentage = 50
    kernel.perf_event_paranoid = 1
    kernel.perf_event_mlock_kb = 516
    kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate = 100000
    kernel.blk_iopoll = 1
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain0.min_interval = 1
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain0.max_interval = 2
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain0.busy_idx = 0
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain0.idle_idx = 0
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain0.newidle_idx = 0
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain0.wake_idx = 0
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain0.forkexec_idx = 0
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain0.busy_factor = 64
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain0.imbalance_pct = 110
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain0.cache_nice_tries = 0
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain0.flags = 687
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain0.name = SIBLING
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain1.min_interval = 1
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain1.max_interval = 4
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain1.busy_idx = 2
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain1.idle_idx = 0
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain1.newidle_idx = 0
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain1.wake_idx = 0
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain1.forkexec_idx = 0
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain1.busy_factor = 64
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain1.imbalance_pct = 125
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain1.cache_nice_tries = 1
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain1.flags = 4655
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain1.name = MC
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu1.domain0.min_interval = 1
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu1.domain0.max_interval = 2
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu1.domain0.busy_idx = 0
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu1.domain0.idle_idx = 0
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu1.domain0.newidle_idx = 0
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu1.domain0.wake_idx = 0
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu1.domain0.forkexec_idx = 0
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu1.domain0.busy_factor = 64
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu1.domain0.imbalance_pct = 110
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu1.domain0.cache_nice_tries = 0
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu1.domain0.flags = 687
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu1.domain0.name = SIBLING
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu1.domain1.min_interval = 1
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu1.domain1.max_interval = 4
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu1.domain1.busy_idx = 2
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu1.domain1.idle_idx = 0
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu1.domain1.newidle_idx = 0
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu1.domain1.wake_idx = 0
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu1.domain1.forkexec_idx = 0
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu1.domain1.busy_factor = 64
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu1.domain1.imbalance_pct = 125
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu1.domain1.cache_nice_tries = 1
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu1.domain1.flags = 4655
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu1.domain1.name = MC
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu2.domain0.min_interval = 1
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu2.domain0.max_interval = 2
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu2.domain0.busy_idx = 0
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu2.domain0.idle_idx = 0
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu2.domain0.newidle_idx = 0
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu2.domain0.wake_idx = 0
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu2.domain0.forkexec_idx = 0
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu2.domain0.busy_factor = 64
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu2.domain0.imbalance_pct = 110
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu2.domain0.cache_nice_tries = 0
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu2.domain0.flags = 687
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu2.domain0.name = SIBLING
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu2.domain1.min_interval = 1
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu2.domain1.max_interval = 4
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu2.domain1.busy_idx = 2
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu2.domain1.idle_idx = 0
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu2.domain1.newidle_idx = 0
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu2.domain1.wake_idx = 0
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu2.domain1.forkexec_idx = 0
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu2.domain1.busy_factor = 64
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu2.domain1.imbalance_pct = 125
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu2.domain1.cache_nice_tries = 1
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu2.domain1.flags = 4655
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu2.domain1.name = MC
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu3.domain0.min_interval = 1
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu3.domain0.max_interval = 2
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu3.domain0.busy_idx = 0
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu3.domain0.idle_idx = 0
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu3.domain0.newidle_idx = 0
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu3.domain0.wake_idx = 0
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu3.domain0.forkexec_idx = 0
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu3.domain0.busy_factor = 64
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu3.domain0.imbalance_pct = 110
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu3.domain0.cache_nice_tries = 0
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu3.domain0.flags = 687
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu3.domain0.name = SIBLING
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu3.domain1.min_interval = 1
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu3.domain1.max_interval = 4
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu3.domain1.busy_idx = 2
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu3.domain1.idle_idx = 0
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu3.domain1.newidle_idx = 0
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu3.domain1.wake_idx = 0
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu3.domain1.forkexec_idx = 0
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu3.domain1.busy_factor = 64
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu3.domain1.imbalance_pct = 125
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu3.domain1.cache_nice_tries = 1
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu3.domain1.flags = 4655
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu3.domain1.name = MC
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu4.domain0.min_interval = 1
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu4.domain0.max_interval = 2
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu4.domain0.busy_idx = 0
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu4.domain0.idle_idx = 0
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu4.domain0.newidle_idx = 0
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu4.domain0.wake_idx = 0
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu4.domain0.forkexec_idx = 0
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu4.domain0.busy_factor = 64
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu4.domain0.imbalance_pct = 110
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu4.domain0.cache_nice_tries = 0
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu4.domain0.flags = 687
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu4.domain0.name = SIBLING
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu4.domain1.min_interval = 1
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu4.domain1.max_interval = 4
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu4.domain1.busy_idx = 2
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu4.domain1.idle_idx = 0
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu4.domain1.newidle_idx = 0
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu4.domain1.wake_idx = 0
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu4.domain1.forkexec_idx = 0
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu4.domain1.busy_factor = 64
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu4.domain1.imbalance_pct = 125
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu4.domain1.cache_nice_tries = 1
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu4.domain1.flags = 4655
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu4.domain1.name = MC
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu5.domain0.min_interval = 1
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu5.domain0.max_interval = 2
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu5.domain0.busy_idx = 0
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu5.domain0.idle_idx = 0
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu5.domain0.newidle_idx = 0
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu5.domain0.wake_idx = 0
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu5.domain0.forkexec_idx = 0
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu5.domain0.busy_factor = 64
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu5.domain0.imbalance_pct = 110
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu5.domain0.cache_nice_tries = 0
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu5.domain0.flags = 687
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu5.domain0.name = SIBLING
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu5.domain1.min_interval = 1
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu5.domain1.max_interval = 4
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu5.domain1.busy_idx = 2
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu5.domain1.idle_idx = 0
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu5.domain1.newidle_idx = 0
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu5.domain1.wake_idx = 0
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu5.domain1.forkexec_idx = 0
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu5.domain1.busy_factor = 64
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu5.domain1.imbalance_pct = 125
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu5.domain1.cache_nice_tries = 1
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu5.domain1.flags = 4655
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu5.domain1.name = MC
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu6.domain0.min_interval = 1
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu6.domain0.max_interval = 2
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu6.domain0.busy_idx = 0
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu6.domain0.idle_idx = 0
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu6.domain0.newidle_idx = 0
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu6.domain0.wake_idx = 0
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu6.domain0.forkexec_idx = 0
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu6.domain0.busy_factor = 64
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu6.domain0.imbalance_pct = 110
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu6.domain0.cache_nice_tries = 0
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu6.domain0.flags = 687
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu6.domain0.name = SIBLING
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu6.domain1.min_interval = 1
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu6.domain1.max_interval = 4
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu6.domain1.busy_idx = 2
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu6.domain1.idle_idx = 0
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu6.domain1.newidle_idx = 0
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu6.domain1.wake_idx = 0
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu6.domain1.forkexec_idx = 0
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu6.domain1.busy_factor = 64
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu6.domain1.imbalance_pct = 125
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu6.domain1.cache_nice_tries = 1
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu6.domain1.flags = 4655
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu6.domain1.name = MC
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu7.domain0.min_interval = 1
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu7.domain0.max_interval = 2
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu7.domain0.busy_idx = 0
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu7.domain0.idle_idx = 0
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu7.domain0.newidle_idx = 0
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu7.domain0.wake_idx = 0
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu7.domain0.forkexec_idx = 0
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu7.domain0.busy_factor = 64
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu7.domain0.imbalance_pct = 110
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu7.domain0.cache_nice_tries = 0
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu7.domain0.flags = 687
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu7.domain0.name = SIBLING
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu7.domain1.min_interval = 1
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu7.domain1.max_interval = 4
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu7.domain1.busy_idx = 2
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu7.domain1.idle_idx = 0
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu7.domain1.newidle_idx = 0
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu7.domain1.wake_idx = 0
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu7.domain1.forkexec_idx = 0
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu7.domain1.busy_factor = 64
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu7.domain1.imbalance_pct = 125
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu7.domain1.cache_nice_tries = 1
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu7.domain1.flags = 4655
    kernel.sched_domain.cpu7.domain1.name = MC

thank you

Comment: Are there any interesting entries in the error log?

Comment: when someone tries to download from server will get request time out error.

Comment: You can post the output of `sysctl -a`. That should do the trick.

Comment: As it stands there is no good way for us to even start to guess at possible causes - Please address the questions asked in the comments by editing your question, and it will automatically be submitted for reopening.  Thanks!

Comment: I edited my first post and posted sysctl -a output...there is more but the editor doesn't allowed me to enter more than 30000 characters. what else are u need for that?

Answer (score 2):

Check your `/etc/sysctl.conf` file for number of ephemeral ports (port range), number of max filehandlers,  and socket memory. All this could impose a limit to how many concurrent requests apache can serve.

Comment: kernel.msgmnb = 65536

Comment: kernel.msgmax = 65536

Comment: kernel.shmmax = 68719476736

Comment: kernel.shmall = 4294967296

Comment: do you mean these? I'm new in these stuff,please help if u can.

Comment: No, I meant system tunable parameters. Run [this script](http://www.shell-tips.com/wp-content/uploads/sysctl-config.sh.txt) on your server and see if the new kernel parameters solves your issues!